# mysql - select true when count is greater than zero

Tags: mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) AS offer_count
  FROM restaurants_offers
WHERE DATE( NOW( ) ) 
   BETWEEN date_start
   AND date_end
AND restaurant_id =1
```

Now, when count is greater than zero I want to select `true` else `false`, instead of count as the query result. How to do that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT IF(COUNT(*) > 0, 'true', 'false') AS NewResult
  FROM restaurants_offers
 WHERE (DATE(NOW())  BETWEEN date_start AND date_end) AND 
       restaurant_id = 1
```

Comment: You can use unquoted `TRUE`/`FALSE` values in MySQL.

Comment: it will simply return 1 and 0 if i will not unquote it.

Comment: Yes I know, MySQL has not implemented the boolean datatype at all and the SQL standard does not specify it as a must. But it's still better than getting one of two string values ('true'/'false') both of which will evaluate to TRUE if checked in a programming language.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) > 0 AS has_offers
  FROM restaurants_offers
WHERE DATE( NOW( ) ) 
   BETWEEN date_start
   AND date_end
AND restaurant_id =1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT case when COUNT(*) > 0 
            then 1
            else 0
       end AS offer_count
FROM restaurants_offers
WHERE DATE( NOW( ) ) 
BETWEEN date_start
AND date_end
AND restaurant_id =1
```

or if you need the words `true`and `false`

```
SELECT case when COUNT(*) > 0 
            then 'true'
            else 'false'
       end AS offer_count
...
```

Comment: Why use case when `IF` would've been shorter?

Comment: You can choose either. I like `case` better. That's all.